# Can Samba report free space per-directory for OS X clients?

Tags: debian, mount, samba, macos

I have a Samba share which spans mount points. Samba is only reporting the available space of the top-level share directory and does not report free space on a per-directory basis, so traversing into the directory tree shows incorrect values for available space.

I understand this is probably due to the way the CIFS protocol works, but since I am running on Linux and my clients are Mac OS X machines, I was wondering if there was any way to configure Samba and OS X to report available space on a per-directory basis?

Example for more detail: my Samba share's root is `/mnt/Media` which is just a small `tmpfs` filesystem under which external drives are mounted:

```
root@subdivisions:/mnt/Media/ExtStorage/TiVo# df -h /mnt/Media /mnt/Media/ArchiveB /mnt/Media/ExtStorage/
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none               10M   12K   10M   1% /mnt/Media
DriveA/Media       14G     0   14G   0% /mnt/Media/DriveA
DriveB/Media      161G     0  161G   0% /mnt/Media/DriveB
```

I am **not** interested in [faking the free space](https://serverfault.com/questions/325052/debian-samba-server-reports-free-size-of-root-drive-not-all-drives) but can do that if there's no other solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No @tmm1 I am still wanting a solution here 

Comment: From what I can tell, the protocol and smbd are doing the right thing. But the client in macOS assumes the free space measured at root applies to all the subdirectories too.

It looks like the issue has been reported multiple times on the Apple forums (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5804160?answerId=31241902022#31241902022) and only affects Finder. `cp` etc from the Terminal work just fine because they ignore the incorrect free size measurements.

Comment: Oh boy. Thanks for the explanation.